# How to identify the culprit in "Error converting data type varchar to numeric"?

Tags: sql-server-2008

An insert statement with a large number of values returns 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.'

How can I find which value actually triggers the error?

MS SQL Server 2008 is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the function ISNUMERIC()

```
select * from table
where isnumeric(column) = 0
```

or

```
declare @v varchar(100)
select @v = 'abd'

select ISNUMERIC(@v)
```

Also take a look at this [IsNumeric, IsInt, IsNumber](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber) post to help you further with these kind of problems

Comment: Thanks, turns out empty quotes were being passed in place of nulls.